# fast, accurate, reliable way to remove undesirable values from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, data-processing

I have a large-ish csv file that has a substantial ammount of dirty data in it, I'd like to clean it up a bit by eliminating all the values that are not absolutely necessary.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zs4d15be9bmv9lf/edsa_data.csv?dl=0) is the file I'm talking about.

It has the components:

`Website`**,**`Title`**,**`Start Date`**,**`Employer`**,**`Location`**,**`lat`**,**`lon`**,**`Country`**,**`Skills11`**,**`Jobs`

but I would like to obliterate all but:

`Employer`**,**`Location`**,**`Country`**,**`Jobs`

Is there a particular tool that is uniquely suited for this task?

Or maybe someone has a handy Python script that can get the job done?

Comment: If it's just a one-time thing, maybe you could open it in Excel and delete those columns?

Comment: I only have libre office- which is an epic piece of crap IMHO- right now I'm iterating on some Python scripts to do it- since- over time the data will change, and maybe python would be faster? I don't really know

Comment: Google Drive? It does the job quite quick :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do it with python writing to a temporary file then replacing the original.

```
import  csv
from operator import itemgetter
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move

with open("edsa_data.csv") as f, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".", delete=False) as tmp:
    # itertools.imap python2
    csv.writer(tmp).writerows(map(itemgetter(3, 5, 7, 9), csv.reader(f)))
move(tmp.name, "edsa_data.csv")
```

For a more generic approach:

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move




def keep_columns(csv_f, keep_cols, **kwargs):
    with open(csv_f) as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w", dir=".", delete=False) as tmp:
        csv.writer(tmp, **kwargs).writerows(itemgetter(*keep_cols)(row) 
                                            for row in csv.reader(f, **kwargs))
    move(tmp.name, csv_f)


keep_columns("edsa_data.csv", (3, 4, 7, 9))
```

For the kwargs you can pass *sep=","* *skipinitialspace=True* etc..

Comment: for some reason it doesn't like the like with `move(move(tmp.name, "edsa_data.csv")`

Comment: he says "invalid syntax" about line 10

Comment: There was actually a missing closing paren

Comment: Are you sure it does the right thing? For instance it yields `N/A,53.841099,United Kingdom,project management` for the 2nd record which I guess should actually be `N/A,Horsforth,United Kingdom,1`, is it becasue of non escaped special characters or missing values or something?

Comment: @s.matthew.english, last column should be index  9 not 8.

Answer (score 2):

For ease of maintenance, I'd use a `DictReader`/`DictWriter` pair.

```
import csv
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as csv_infile:
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as csv_outfile:
        csv_in = csv.DictReader(csv_infile)
        csv_out = csv.DictWriter(
            csv_outfile,
            ['Employer','Location','Country','Jobs'],
            extrasaction='ignore')
        csv_out.writeheader()
        csv_out.writerows(csv_in)
```